# Sort Worksheet that's not Active/Visible

Tags: vba, excel

So I use the code below to sort the Worksheet, and it works...but only if you're on the Worksheet it's trying to sort.  If you're not it sends an Error:

> Run-time error '1004':  The Sort reference is not valid.  Make sure
>   that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort box
>   isn't the same or blank.

I'm going to need to keep this Worksheet hidden, so making it active isn't really an option.  Am I missing a line in the code?

Thanks

CODE:

```
Sheet23.Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, _ 
               key2:=Range("B2"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always qualify Range() or Cells() with a worksheet, otherwise they refer to the ActiveSheet:

```
Sheet23.Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Sheet23.Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, _ 
                            key2:=Sheet23.Range("B2"), order2:=xlDescending, _
                            Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a relative reference for your reference cells:

```
Sheet23.Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, _ 
           key2:=Range("B2"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

`=Range("A2")` Will always refer to the active sheet.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet23").Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet23").Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, _ 
           key2:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet23").Range("B2"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Should give you the desired result.